# Can't find public network if here's an other, password protected one

Tags: network, wifi

I've got a weird problem with my 2019 MBP: it is not able to scan/recognize a public network `XYZ`, if there's also an other `XYZ` network that is password protected.

Practical example: when I go to a Starbucks, I know there are two networks:

- a public `Starbucks`, where clients can connect
- a WPA2 protected `Starbucks` network (used most likely by its employees?)

now, with both my Samsung smartphone and my work laptop, I can see both networks, and I'm able to connect to the public `Starbucks` one.

My MPB however isn't able at all to find Starbuck's public wifi, and only shows up the password protected one.

What should I do to fix this odd issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a workaround, I went to `Network preferences` -> `Advanced` , then clicked on the `+` button and added a new wifi hotspot named `Starbucks`, without security.
Clicked `Ok`, then `Apply` et voilà, MPB connected..